# Интересная задача с именами свойств

Tags: php

Есть кусок задачи:

```
$var = Class::method();
echo "[$var]"; \\ выводит "[text text]"
Class2::XXX()->$var->method2();
```

В упор не пойму, как можно обратиться к свойству $var, если там строка из 2 слов 'text text'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такого можно достичь при использовании перегрузки в php. Для этого есть магические методы, в данном случае нам поможет метод `__get ( string $name )`. Пример кода ниже. При вызове несуществующего свойства, класс вызовет метод `__get()` в котором Мы преобразуем входящее значение в нужное свойство и получим из него данные, в данном случае объект текущего класса например и вызовем еще 1 метод.

```
class Bar {
    public function method2() {
        return 'Hello World';
    }
}

class Foo {
    public $testtest = Bar::class;

    public function __get(string $name) {
        $myProp = str_replace(' ', '', $name);
        return new $this->$myProp;
    }
}

$myClass = new Foo();
$var = 'test test';
echo $myClass->$var->method2();
```

Comment: Благодарю, про магию знал, но не дошло что решение в ней)